# Do I have to Define Session and S3 as a package variable or Create instance in every api request

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

Do I have to Define Session and S3 as a package variable or Create instance  in every api request.sample code as following.thanks a lot.

```
var AWSSession *session.Session
var S3Client *s3.S3

func InitAws() error {

    log.Info("InitAws")

    AWSSession, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region:      aws.String("XXXX"),
        Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials( "XX","XX",""), //just for test
    })

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.Info("InitAws S3 Client")
    S3Client = s3.New(AWSSession)

    log.Info("InitAws end")
    return nil
}
```

Comment: check the overview in this link, Session should be cached when possible and used across your service clients.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/session/

Comment: thanks. i should have read the document carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [package documentation says](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session):

> Sessions are safe to use concurrently as long as the Session is not being modified. Sessions should be cached when possible, because creating a new Session will load all configuration values from the environment, and config files each time the Session is created. Sharing the Session value across all of your service clients will ensure the configuration is loaded the fewest number of times possible.

Do create a single session and reuse it.

Whether you should store that single session in a package-level variable or pass it through function arguments is a separate question with opinionated answers.